# XBRL support in BPEL?

Tags: bpel, xbrl

Does BPEL support XBRL standard?
Very few responses on google tells that Oracle DB adapter in BPEL can be used to interact(perform DML operations) with Oracle XML DB by calling stored procedure.

However we have a requirement that the BPEL should interact(perform DML operations) with Oracle XML DB after the extension XBRL has been applied to DB.

Is there any way to deal with it? Can any BPEL adapter be configured? Please let me know on how to configure the same.